# Make object's properties available inside function

Tags: javascript

I would like to do the following.I have a code like this:

```
var obj = {
    method : function() {}
};


var func = function() {
    return method(); //method is undefined here
};

func(); // What to do here?
```

Is it possible to call func in a way that it will see the method inside from obj as it was given for example as a parameter. I want to use obj.method inside func, without writing 'obj.' before and without modifying func itself. Is there any hack possible to achieve this?
In other words, is it possible to force obj as a closure into func?
I tried:

```
with(obj) {
    func();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone, any ideas? Or is it the only option to get the body of the function as string, put 'with(obj)' inside it and then create a new function out of it?

Clarification:
Because this code will be in a helper class 'eval' is OK. Which I don't want is the modification of the function through .toString(), because browsers implement it differently.

Comment: If I understand your question, you may need to add `method` to the global namespace (or whatever namespace you're working in, if it's a module): `var method = obj.method`. This will allow the call to `func();` to work as you want, using the correct `method`.

Comment: It's a good point but in the real code, obj has got a lot of methods, with which I don't want to pollute the global namespace of the whole app.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, using `eval` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)):

```
var obj = {
    method : function() {console.log("it workes!");}
};


var func = function() {
    return method(); //method is undefined here
};

var newfunc = (function (obj, func) {
    var method = obj.method;
    eval("var f = " + func.toString());
    return f;
}(obj, func));

newfunc(); //it workes
```

Basically you're just creating a new scope with a local variable called `method` and re-evaluating the function body in this scope. So you're basically creating a new function with the same body. I don't really like this approach and I wouldn't recommend it, but considering your constraints, it might be the only solution.

And yes, it still requires you to write `obj.method`, but not inside of `func`. So I figured, it should be ok.

**EDIT**

So here is a version, in which you don't have to specify the property name manually:

```
var newfunc = (function (__obj__, __func__) {
    for (var __key__ in __obj__) {
        if (__obj__.hasOwnProperty(__key__)) {
            eval("var " + __key__ + " = " + __obj__[__key__]);
        }
    }
    eval("var __f__ = " + func.toString());
    return __f__;
}(obj, func));
```

This also done by using `eval()`.

Note that I changed all remaining local variables to a names containing underscores, to minimize the probability of name collisions with properties inside `obj`.

Note also that not all valid property names are valid variable names. You could have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    "my func": function () {}
}
```

But if you would use this object you would generate a syntax error with the above method, because it would try to evaluate:

```
var my func = ...
```

As apsillers said in the comment section, it gets even worse if you don't have control over the properties of `obj`. In this case you shouldn't use `eval` at all, because you would make cross-site scripting attacks very easy (example from apsillers):

```
var obj = {
    "a; alert('xss'); var b": function () {}
}
```

would evaluate to 3 different statements:

```
var a;
alert('xss');
var b = function () {};
```

Comment: You're close. Can you suggest a way to be able not to write out "var method = o.method" by hand for each of obj's methods? Therefore, if obj gets new methods, this code needs no modification.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi As long as we're doing `eval`, you could do something like `for(key in o) { var varString += "var " + key + "=" + o[key].toString() + ";" }` and then `eval(varString);` I'm curious why you need to do this in the first place; you might possibly have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/186560).

Comment: Note, however, that this approach is very vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks (like much `eval` code is); consider a property defined by `obj["a; alert('xss'); var b"]`

Comment: @apsillers you're right, that's definitely something one has to consider.

Comment: Yes I took that in consideration, but won't be a problem. My last question is if it will be working in all modern browsers? Won't be the different implementations of .toString() causing problems?

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi the `toString` method, applied on functions, will generally return the source code of that function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) | [Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2)). So it SHOULD work everywhere.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi In particular, the spec requires that the stringified function "...has the syntax of a *FunctionDeclaration*," which means it will necessarily be able to be parsed by `eval`. (Whether browsers actually adhere to the spec is, of course, a separate matter, but I'd agree with basilikum's comment that it will work virtually anywhere.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you define `method` separately:

```
var obj = {
    method : function() {}
},
method = obj.method;

// rest of code
```

This is because the `method` reference inside `func()` assumes the `window.` namespace; thus, without modifying `func()` itself, it can't be done sanely.

Comment: this requires modifying `func`, which he doesn't want

Comment: It is true but I have func as I wrote, without this, I have no control on how it was defined.

Comment: @basilikum Right, I skipped over the details.

Comment: It's still not good for me, because this way method will be in the global namespace which I don't want to allow.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi The only other way is `eval()` which I didn't consider for my answer.

Comment: @Jack If you think it is impossible without eval, you can post it as an answer, because that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

More clarified version based on basilikum's answer, and I've found a simplification with 'with':

```
var obj = {
    method : function() { return "it workes!"; }
};


var func = function() {
    return method(); //method is undefined here
};

(function (obj, func) {
    with(obj) {
        eval("var __res__ = (" + func.toString() + ")()");        
    }
    return __res__;
}(obj, func));

>> "It workes!"
```